# Simplify $\prod_{k=1}^{l} \sum_{r=d}^m {{m}\choose{r}} \left(N-k \right)^{r} k^{m-r+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

Is it possible to simplify  the following product of sums
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{l}  \sum_{r=d}^m  {{m}\choose{r}} \left(N-k \right)^{r} k^{m-r+1}
\end{align}
where $N>l$?

I was thinking that we can multiply and divide by $N^{m+1}$ to make it look more like a  Binomial summation

\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^{l}  \sum_{r=d}^m \frac{N^{m+1}}{N^{m+1}}  {{m}\choose{r}} \left(N-k \right)^{r} k^{m-r+1}= N^{r(m+1)}\prod_{k=1}^{l}  \sum_{r=d}^m   {{m}\choose{r}} \left(1-\frac{k}{N} \right)^{r} \left(\frac{k}{N} \right)^{m-r+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: **If** $d = 0$ then the inner sum may be simplified with Binomial theorem, and the rest sorts itself out. Otherwise, I do not believe it has some magnificent formula.

Comment: @Sisyphus Thank you. I  was wondering if we can simplify it by exchanging product and sum?